# Scraping poorly coded website with php

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

Ok, so I've been using simple_html_dom.php that is free for download from Sourceforge. I want to scrape some websites, but those websites are pretty old, one is from 2009, and they are poorly coded. This php file (simple_html_dom) uses DOMDocument and that stuff, so when you search something, you search it by tag name, attribute, or smth else. Now, I have a div element and inside I have random text, and after that other elements.

```
<div id="rcontent">
    <font size = 3>
      Random text going here cuz I'm a poor coder and I made it hard for scraping<br><br>

      <a href="One.xls">Text.</a>
      <a href="Two.test.txt">Text2.</a>
      <a href="Three.pdf">Text3</a><br><br>......
   </font>
</div>
```

How should I extract just this text, before this anchor tags? When I use something like inner text, I get the whole div, and I don't want that. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a dom tree. every chunk of text is a node, so find the `<font>` tag, then its next sibling would be the "random text..." text node.

Comment: Thanks, ill try that. It never crossed my mind.